# How to aggregate unique users by hour in Amazon Redshift?

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregation, amazon-redshift

With Amazon Redshift I want to count every unique visitor.

A unique visitor is a visitor who did not visit less than an hour previously.

So for the following rows of users and timestamps we'd get a total count of 4 unique visitors with user1 and user2 counting as 2 respectively.

Please note that I do not want to aggregate by hour in a 24 hour day. I want to aggregate by an hour after the time stamp of the users first visit.

I'm guessing a straight up SQL expression won't do it.

```
user1,"2015-07-13 08:28:45.247000" 
user1,"2015-07-13 08:30:17.247000"
user1,"2015-07-13 09:35:00.030000" 
user1,"2015-07-13 09:54:00.652000"
user2,"2015-07-13 08:28:45.247000" 
user2,"2015-07-13 08:30:17.247000"
user2,"2015-07-13 09:35:00.030000" 
user2,"2015-07-13 09:54:00.652000"
```

So user1 arrives at 8:28, that counts as one hit. He comes back at 8:30 which counts as zero. He then comes back at 9:35 which is more than an hour from 8:30, so he gets another hit. Then he comes back at 9:35 which is only 5 minutes from the last time 9:30 so this counts as zero. The total is 2 hits for user1. The same thing happens for user2 meaning two hits each bringing it to a final total of 4.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lag` to accomplish this. However, you will also have to handle for end of day by partitioning on `day` as well. The query below would be a starting point.

```
with prev as (
select user_id,
datecol,
coalesce(lag(datecol) over(partition by user_id order by datecol),0) as prev
from tablename
)
select user_id,
sum(case when datediff(minutes, datecol, prev) >=60 then 1 else 0 end) as totalvisits
from prev
group by user_id
```

Comment: you can `group by` each day then, to get the appropriate result.

Comment: Or use the Window function: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_LAG.html